# Como hace una suma de columnas y restarlas

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy tratando de hacer una consulta en SQL Server donde ocupo sumar valores de una columna según la condición de otra columna con la condición de que se agrupen con mi numero de parte.

la siguiente consulta es lo que tengo hasta ahorita

```
 SELECT
       re.APZ_NP, en.APZ_NP, (re.Entrada - en.Entrada1) Total
    FROM (
        SELECT APZ_NP, SUM(APZ_Cantidad) Entrada FROM [BEYONZ].[dbo].[CP_APZ]
    WHERE APZ_Status = 2
    GROUP BY APZ_NP 
    ) re ,(
        SELECT APZ_NP, SUM(APZ_Cantidad) Entrada1 FROM [BEYONZ].[dbo].[CP_APZ]
    WHERE APZ_Status = 3
    GROUP BY APZ_NP 
    ) en
    GROUP BY re.APZ_NP, en.APZ_NP, re.Entrada, en.Entrada1
```

[image: el siguiente es el resultado que me arroja, me agrupa valores que no son iguales y lo restas. lo cual no quiero.]

[image: y esta es mi tabla con la cual quiero hacer mi consulta]

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Creo que hace falta mejorar la descripción de lo que quieres lograr, pues no queda muy claro. Puedes también incluir un ejemplo de los datos de entrada y la salida exacta que deseas producir con dicha entrada, además de la explicación, pues eso muchas veces ayuda a aclararla mucho. Un saludo.

Comment: No se entiende muy bien lo que necesitas pero hasta donde veo intentas sumar dos varchar. Asumo que quieres concatenarlos (Hacer de los dos uno solo). Si lo que deseas es concatenarlos usa la funcion Concat().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que tus subconsultas no tienen condiciones de join y además estás agrupando por todas las columnas, por lo que no se genera la lógica correcta.

Sin embargo, en vez de corregir paso a paso, dejo una alternativa más eficiente que hace uso de agregados condicionales para saber cuando sumar y cuando restar.

```
SELECT APZ_NP,  
    SUM( CASE WHEN APZ_Status = 2 THEN APZ_Cantidad ELSE 0 END) Entrada ,  
    SUM( CASE WHEN APZ_Status = 3 THEN APZ_Cantidad ELSE 0 END) Entrada1 ,  
    SUM( CASE WHEN APZ_Status = 2 THEN APZ_Cantidad ELSE -APZ_Cantidad END) Total 
FROM [BEYONZ].[dbo].[CP_APZ]
WHERE APZ_Status IN( 2, 3)
GROUP BY APZ_NP;
```

Comment: gracias no, sabes cuanto tiempo tenia intentando hace esta consulta